# Convert Atom XML to plain text

Tags: xml, atom-feed

I have backed up my blog from blogger. The format of the file is Atom XML. What's a quick way to turn it into plaintext? Opening it in a browser leads to formatting errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample Atom to HTML XSLT stylesheet: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1162

If you attach it to your XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my-atom-to-html-stylesheet.xsl"?>
...
```

..then opening the XML in a modern browser will produce nice readable text.

If you change `<xsl:output method="html"/>` to `<xsl:output method="text"/>` and remove all the extra markup in the style sheet then you will get pure text output.

Comment: perfect. if only i'd seen this answer before i wrestled with Python feedparser to get the job done...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you want to include in your plain text version, a simple XSLT transform would work.

If you give an example of your ATOM XML and what you would want the text output to look like, I can give you an example.